# can fontspec work with CMYK colors?

Tags: xetex, color, fontspec, cmyk

Can fontspec be used to manage a document's fonts if the fonts need to use the CMYK color model? [The fontspec documentation](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/xetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf), section 6.1, says that fontspec uses RGB colors. My experimentation (MWE below) seems to confirm that fontspec will convert CMYK colors passed to it into noticeably different RGB equivalents.

PDF output of MWE (using XeLaTeX, fontspec, xcolor):

[image: PDF output of MWE (using XeLaTeX); fontspec changes CMYK colors to approximate RGB equivalents]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{mycyan}{cmyk}{1,0,0,0}
\definecolor{mymagenta}{cmyk}{0,1,0,0}
\definecolor{myyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,1,0}
\definecolor{myblack}{cmyk}{0,0,0,1}

\begin{document} 

Without fontspec:

\textcolor{mycyan}{\rule{10pt}{10pt}}
\textcolor{mycyan}{XXX Cyan text (CMYK 1,0,0,0)}

\textcolor{mymagenta}{\rule{10pt}{10pt}}
\textcolor{mymagenta}{XXX Magenta text (CMYK 0,1,0,0)}

\textcolor{myyellow}{\rule{10pt}{10pt}}
\textcolor{myyellow}{XXX Yellow text (CMYK 0,0,1,0)}

\textcolor{myblack}{\rule{10pt}{10pt}}
\textcolor{myblack}{XXX Black text (CMYK 0,0,0,1)}

With fontspec:

\textcolor{mycyan}{\rule{10pt}{10pt}}
\fontspec[Color=mycyan]{Arial} XXX Cyan text (CMYK 1,0,0,0)

\textcolor{mymagenta}{\rule{10pt}{10pt}}
\fontspec[Color=mymagenta]{Arial} XXX Magenta text (CMYK 0,1,0,0)

\textcolor{myyellow}{\rule{10pt}{10pt}}
\fontspec[Color=myyellow]{Arial} XXX Yellow text (CMYK 0,0,1,0)

\textcolor{myblack}{\rule{10pt}{10pt}}
\fontspec[Color=myblack]{Arial} XXX Black text (CMYK 0,0,0,1)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `\textcolor`? `\textcolor{mycyan}{\fontspec{Arial} XXX Cyan text (CMYK 1,0,0,0)}` is working fine. (Leaving aside, that it would be better to set the document font globally in the preamble, instead of switching adhoc inside of `\textcolor`)

Comment: Also: The issue is known for a long time now → https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/129

Comment: @DG' Your suggestion worked for me too! Thank you. It's a fine workaround that enables me to use fontspec in sync with CMYK text colors. If you write up your suggestion as an answer, I'll select it as correct.

Comment: Well, it seems that the considerations [here (click)](http://lea.verou.me/2009/03/100-cyan-in-cmyk-is-not-rgb0255255/) apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fontspec can work with CMYK colors, if you use `\textcolor` instead of fontspec's `Color` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\definecolor{mycyan}{cmyk}{1,0,0,0}

\begin{document}

Without fontspec:

\textcolor{mycyan}{\rule{10pt}{10pt}}
\textcolor{mycyan}{XXX Cyan text (CMYK 1,0,0,0)}

With fontspec:

\textcolor{mycyan}{\rule{10pt}{10pt}}
\textcolor{mycyan}{\fontspec{Arial} XXX Cyan text (CMYK 1,0,0,0)}

\end{document}
```

[image]